# How to do an ease in transition after a react if statement

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a catalogue which has a filter component. Once the filter button is clicked, it triggers a variable to turn `true` which then switches what is being shown on the screen. I want to know how I can make this switch smooth and ease in using css. Here is my code:

```
<div>
                {this.state.showProjects === true &&
                    <div className="test">
                        {this.state.projects && this.state.projects.map((project) => (
                            <ProjectDetails key={project._id} project={project}/>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                }
                {this.state.showProjects === false &&
                    <div className="initial-screen"> 
                        Enter filter options to get started!
                    </div>
                }
                
            </div>
```

Where and how should I incorporate the css `ease` property?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what your ask is, you can implement a class-based solution that has your transition effects in there.

```
<div>
    <div className=`test content ${this.state.showProjects && 'active'}`>
        {this.state.projects && this.state.projects.map((project) => (
            <ProjectDetails key={project._id} project={project}/>
         ))}
     </div>
     <div className=`initial-screen content ${!this.state.showProjects && 'active'}`> 
         Enter filter options to get started!
     </div> 
</div>
```

I added another class called `content` which would have the main transition styling that you would need for your animations. The `active` class would be your identifier as to what is currently being displayed.

```
.content {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duraction: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;

    &.active {
        opacity: 100;
    }
}
```

This would just add a simple fade-in/fade-out, but you can use this at a simple template for you to use to start adding in more styling; like movement.

Comment: For some reason the back ticks ` are giving me an error, do you know why I can't write code in those back ticks?

Comment: The backticks are for just template literals, so you shouldn't be getting any errors. Can you post what error you're running in to when adding them? Also, what code editor are you using for this?